# Render Markdown Code Example with String (JSDoc2MD)

Tags: markdown, jsdoc, jsdoc2md

I am using JSDoc comments in a JS file and running JSDoc2MD to render those comments into a markdown readme.md file.  I want to include code examples in my documentation using the [@example tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-example.html) from JSDoc. I'm having trouble with rendering a string with quotes.

In my JS comments I have:

```
/** @example
 * // returns true
 * yesNo("Do you like cheese?");
*/
```

This comment becomes the following in json:

```
{
"examples": [
      "// returns true\nyesNo(\"Do you like cheese?\");"
    ]
}
```

I have a custom handlebars template setup that JSDoc2MD uses to generate the readme. In my handlebars template I have:

````
```js
{{#each examples}}
{{this}}
{{/each}}
```
````

The generated readme has the html name instead of quotation marks:

````
```js

// returns true
yesNo(&quot;Do you like cheese?&quot;);

```
````

So the markdown output looks good expect for the quotation marks:

```
// returns true
yesNo(&quot;Do you like cheese?&quot;);
```

Anyone else working with JSDoc2MD having this issue? Did I just type something wrong here?

Comment: What's the problem? The HTML entities display as quotes in the browser. In fact, some Markdown implementations will convert various characters to their HTML entities.

Comment: And [most](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=yesNo(%26quot%3BDo+you+like+cheese%3F%26quot%3B)%3B) Markdown implementations pass HTML entities through unaltered. By the way, use the "preview" tab there to see that browsers display things correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a handlebars thing, try this:

````
```js
{{#each examples}}
{{{this}}}
{{/each}}
```
````

note the triple brackets around `this`.. see [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html) and look for "triple stash".

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks Lloyd.